# I have one project in magento 2 and two diffrent themes for desktop and mobile

Tags: ipad, browser, safari

I have some issues in magento 2 project i m working on on largest project in magento 2 for use two theme different theme for desktop and mobile so facing issue on ipad safari browser issue like mobile theme not detect in this deceive.

If any one can help me so please......

Issues in Ipad safari borwser.